# Is there a way to do a background fetch of a PARSE table in iOS 7 or 8?

Tags: background, parse-platform, fetch

I am using PARSE and would like to do a background Fetch so that while the app is not in the foreground it grabs a row of a table in a table.

Can I do that?  And if so, is there any example code out there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's nothing specific about parse. You might want to read up on relevant ios documentation. This tutorial seems like a good place to start: http://www.devfright.com/ios-7-background-app-refresh-tutorial/

Comment: I have read the iOS documentation and I have background fetch working, However I specifically need it to talk to a PARSE table.  That is the piece I am missing.

Comment: @MichaelMeinberg it wouldn't no different to fetching data as defined in the documentation using PFQuery.